# Why does multiplying audio signal amplitude by any coefficient doesn't change it?

Tags: python, audio, librosa

Suppose you have the following float32 audio representation loaded from any wav file using the librosa package:

```
import librosa

wav_x_path = "any_wav_filepath.wav"
wav_source, _ = librosa.load(wav_x_path, sr=16000)
```

If you then will try to play this audio using, for example, a jupyter notebook, the following snippets sounds in the same way:

```
from IPython.display import display, Audio

display(Audio(wav_source * 2, rate=sampling_rate))
display(Audio(wav_source * 200, rate=sampling_rate))
display(Audio(wav_source / 200, rate=sampling_rate))
```

Why does it happen that changing audio aptitude (if I correctly understand what wav_source contains audio amplitude), doesn't affect how the audio sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [IPython.display.Audio](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Audio) there is an argument `normalize` which decides whether to apply automatic scaling of the volume. The default is `normalize=True`, which is why different amplitude scales is played back at the same level.

Use `display(Audio(wav_source * 2, rate=sampling_rate, normalize=False))` and you should be able to hear the difference.

Comment: Is this how all modern audio players like VLC or QuickTime works? So they are just basically doing normalisation before playing?

Comment: No, most desktop audio players will not normalize the audio by default. But some of the music services do, like Spotify and Apple Music. https://artists.spotify.com/help/article/loudness-normalization
Music is generally expected to be mastered to a specific loudness level though.